# CRUD operation using Hibernate on table without Primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate. I read that in entity classes, we must have a primary key defined using `@Id`(reading annotation tutorial).

Now my question is suppose I have primary key defined in my object using `@Id` but my database table doesn't have any primary key defined, in that case will i be able to perform operations on that table using hibernate. In other word, will I be able to do **CRUD** operations successfully i.e. without any impact on that table?

Comment: There's a really easy way to find out.

Comment: Just try it out. Also..having table without of primary key..not a good idea.

Comment: It will work only if the column indeed uniquely identifies the row. But if it does, what do you gain by not making it a primary key?

Comment: A database table without a primary key doesn't make sense.